# How to syncronize a working queue with a file directory

Tags: blueprism

In Blue Prism, I want my work queue to consist of alle files added to a file directory. The item key is the filename. I solve this by reading all the filenames, and then loop through each one, check if it is in the queue, and if not, add it. 
There will be thousands of files in the directory, so I don't want to loop through all files every time the process starts. 
Alternatively, using "get all completed items", I can get the itemID of the completed items, but then I have to use "get item data" on each one to get the filename to check if the file needs to be added to the queue. Any better ideas ?

Comment: Well, IMO the easiest thing to do would be to differentiate the input. For example use separate directory for new files and move them to target directory after they're added to the queue or processed, or add some prefix to the file names that will help BP filter through them (e.g. new__filename; old__filename).

Comment: You can move the file from one directory to another (lets say Success/Completed) which you added to BP queue. So the input directory will always be empty when new batch of files are coming. Once the BOT starts next time, BOT will pick new files from file directory and it will not loop through the previous available and new files, it will loop through only new available files.

Answer (score -1):

That's a interesting problem.

It must be possible to achieve that by doing SQL query on BP database. If you have an access to it, then this might be the simplest and best solution. I can't help you with that though, as I've never done that.

A simpler solution would be to make a snapshot of the input folder whenever the queue in populated and store it. I've did similar thing in my recent project :)

Example flow that would involve a snapshot:

First, I create an Excel workbook with data from current run (in a sheet "New") and a previous run (in sheet "Old"). I'd save it in some kind of internal location.

1. Get a list of all input files
2. Open a previous excel workbook
3. Remove data from "Old" worksheet
4. Move data from worksheet "New" to "Old"
5. Paste a list of all input files to "New" worksheet
6. Save and close Workbook
7. Run OleDB query to retrieve a list of files that are in "New" sheet, but are not in "Old" sheet.

Comment: While using BP to do SQL queries on a BP database might be the simplest and most stable solution, it is not the best in regards to RPA, as it violates the ROM dictate of replicating the the users work process with the bot while still ensuring the user can replicate the work process of a bot should it fail.